# How to ignore/eliminate difference Playwright screenshots in headed and headless runs?

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, screenshot, playwright

Testing an application with Playwright, I have a little problem with screenshot tests - they failed with a kind of error:
Error: Screenshot comparison failed:

Expected an image 200px by 167px, received 200px by 168px.

So the screenshot differs by 1px in case of --headed and normal headless run.

Any adding of threshold to expect or adding anything like

```
    toHaveScreenshot: {
      maxDiffPixels: 10,
    },

    toMatchSnapshot: {
      maxDiffPixelRatio: 0.1,
    },
```

doesn't help. I suppose because in my case the difference is not some elements looks different in these 2 cases, but because size of element which I take screenshot of, is different and it is an immediate fail of the test.

So, I'd like to either ignore this difference (in test or even in playwright config) or understand why this difference appear and get rid off it (not sure if it is possible).

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77149729

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Still the same issue: Error: Screenshot comparison failed:
Expected an image 200px by 167px, received 200px by 166px. 161 pixels (ratio 0.01 of all image pixels) are different.

Comment: Is there any specific url/page you test? Code to reproduce? Which browser, resolution?

Answer (score 0):

It probably fails because in your toHaveScreenshot, you entered: maxDiffPixels: 10, but in reality you are missing a whole row of 200px.

You could also try setting a setViewportSize

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the suggestion of setting the viewport size, you could use the clip option of page.screenshot(), setting the x and y values to zero and the width and height to 200 and 167.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in a manual wait of half a second appears to have solved this issue for me, I guess that's the extra time the browser window needed to resize itself correctly.

```
await page.waitForTimeout(500)
```